# Binding the Itemsource of a Listbox to a method in Code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a Database and a XAML File an in there I have two Listboxes, the first one (*lbAg*) to list the topics (*ag_name*, like finances, HR, etc.) and the second one (*liAn*) to list the tasks in that field which have to be done (*an_anligen*, like paying the accountant etc..).
The thing is, I want the Items of *liAn* to be the tasks of the selected Item from *liAg*, but only if the attribute an_fertig (an_done) to be false. This I want to achieve by binding it to a method in the code behind.

Please help,
Thanks in advance.
XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" 
         Grid.RowSpan="2"
         x:Name="liAg" 
         Loaded="liAg_Loaded" 
         DisplayMemberPath="ag_name"  />

<ListBox Grid.Column="1" 
         Grid.RowSpan="2"
         x:Name="liAn"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding liAn_Items}"
         DisplayMemberPath="an_titel" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class Main : UserControl
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DbEntities db = new DbEntities();

    private void liAg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        liAg.ItemsSource = db.ag_arbeitsgemeinschaft.ToList();
    }

    private void liAn_Items(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string liag = liAg.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(liag);

        var erg = from a in db.an_anliegen
            where a.an_ag == liag && a.an_fertig != true
            select a;

        liAn.ItemsSource = erg.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem ? `liAn_Items` this method will show items in `liAn` listBox

Comment: you can call this method `SelectionChanged` event of `lbAg`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to bind to a method, you can use the [`ObjectDataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider?view=netframework-4.8): [Microsoft Docs: How to: Bind to a Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-a-method).

You have many options. You can make use of the `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event to trigger the database query.

I highly recommend not to mix XAML data binding and direct property assignment using C#. You should use data binding when possible.

I have created some [`DependencyProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) data source properties for the `ListBox.ItemsSource` properties to bind to. Since you didn't supplied any details about your data item type, I bound the `ListBox` to a collection of the fictional `DataItem` type:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DataItems",
    typeof(IEnumerable),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

  public IEnumerable DataItems
  {
    get => (IEnumerable) GetValue(MainWindow.DataItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.DataItemsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TasksProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Tasks",
    typeof(IEnumerable),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

  public IEnumerable Tasks
  {
    get => (IEnumerable) GetValue(MainWindow.TasksProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.TasksProperty, value);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.DataItems = db.ag_arbeitsgemeinschaft.ToList();
  }

  private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Cast the ListBox.SelectedItem from object to the data type
    DataItem selectedItem = e.AddedItems.OfType<DataItem>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (selectedItem == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Access the selected item's members
    string displayedValue = selectedItem.ag_name;

    // Execute query
    var erg = from a in db.an_anliegen
            where a.an_ag == displayedValue && !a.an_fertig
            select a;

    // Update binding source of the ListBox named 'liAn'
    this.Tasks = erg.ToList();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <ListBox x:Name="liAg" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}, 
                         Path=DataItems}"
           DisplayMemberPath="ag_name"
           SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />

  <ListBox x:Name="liAn"  
           ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}, 
                         Path=Tasks}"
           DisplayMemberPath="an_titel" />
</Window>
```